# Query Kafka materialized views efficiency

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, materialized-views

I would like to create a scalable distributed application that use materialized views instead of traditional database.

Could you tell me please how efficient are materialized **get**s views compared to **SELECT**s by id? I'm afraid that this "hops" between different instances using REST will slow down them a lot.

```java
org.apache.kafka.streams.state.HostInfo hostInfo = interactiveQueryService.getHostInfo("store-name",
                        key, keySerializer);

if (interactiveQueryService.getCurrentHostInfo().equals(hostInfo)) {

    //query from the store that is locally available
}
else {
    //query from the remote host
}
```

How reliable is this? How to differ lack of element and unsuccessful "hop"?

Comment: I think you'll have to try things out in your environment to get precise/useful numbers.

Generally, most distributed key-value systems will require some kind of lookup to understand which machine hosts a key.  Given that, I think you'll have some of this overhead in general.  (I'm not seeing a great way around it.)

Comment: The tricky part is to avoid unsuccessful "hops" that will latency. This is true especially if you have many instances (more state is spread out between individual instances).

`success_rate = 1/number_of_instances`

Smart load balancer can perform the routing logic before sending the initial request to the microservice. It applies the partitioner logic to obtain the partition ID, compares it against its internal table of consumer group assignments, and then forwards request accordingly. @GeoJim how about that?

Comment: Makes sense.  Your idea of applying the partitioner logic is the kind of thing I was meaning when I said "Generally, most distributed key-value systems will require some kind of lookup to understand which machine hosts a key."

That work will some time; ideally, it will be faster than making a bunch of network requests.  Of course, there may be a need to look up / maintain partition assignments (since those may be dynamic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tricky part is to avoid unsuccessful "hops" that will increase latency. This is true especially if you have many instances (more state is spread out between individual instances) `success_rate = 1/number_of_instances`. There is basically two ways to avoid that:

1. Smart load balancer can perform the routing logic before sending the initial request to the microservice. It applies the partitioner logic to obtain the partition ID, compares it against its internal table of consumer group assignments, and then forwards request accordingly.
2. It is also possible to represent read requests as streams of events, and send oth the read events and write events through a stream processor; the processor responds to read events by emitting the result the read to an output stream.

Answer (score 0):

In the actual version of Apache Kafka Streams (Up to 3.0 for now), Interactive queries are not available each time the stream group is repartitioning.
This functionality of offline queries is on the backlog.

Then i would not recommend to use this strategy for now.

Comment: Could you send a link for offline queries feature?